# MediaTypeNotAcceptable with SpringBoot RestController

Tags: spring-boot, controller, media-type

I have a rest controller with a GetMapping that produces media type "Plain_text". When an exception occurs in the underlying service, it will be handled by the controller advice and the controller advice returns an object that will be serialized to JSON.

In the happy path, where the service doesn't throw any exception, I'm getting a correct response. But in case of error scenarios, I'm getting an exception with error "Could not find acceptable representation". If I removed the produces tag, the controller is working fine.

Is there a way in spring boot to let an api return plain text media type and in case of errors, return a Json response?

Here is my code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/sample")
public class SampleController() {

   @Autowired
   SampleService service;

   @GetMapping(produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
   public String getString(){
      return service.getString();
   }

}
```

ControllerAdvice:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class SampleControllerAdvice(){

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ExceptionHandler({SampleNotFoundException.class})
    public SampleErrorResponse handleException(Exception ex) {
        return new SampleErrorResponse(e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Comment: First of all, can you put as params of your method in your controllerAdive ((HttpServletRequest req, SampleNotFoundException ex)) rather than Exception ex
second think you realy need text_plain ? 
Third point, how you test you get rest method ?

Answer (score 0):

This looks related to [SPR-16318](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16318), which has been fixed in Spring Framework 5.1 - this is the version used in Spring Boot 2.1.

You should upgrade to Spring Boot 2.1+ to get that fix in your application.